# How to parse python file in Nodejs?

Tags: node.js

I'm in a project, I need to parse python file, get the doc string, the properties, and the class name by Nodejs. I know there is a ast module in python to parse python source file to a syntax tree, is there similar module in Nodejs so that I can parse python source file?

Comment: this maybe a good starting point https://github.com/differentmatt/filbert

Comment: Are you sure you need to parse the code ? you can get tree using ctags also...

Comment: @YohanesGultom looks like fibert doesn't  recognize base class. as I write like this:
class ExceptTest(TestCase, object):
there is no base class info

Comment: @georoot what is that?

Answer (score 0):

There are Python grammars available for ANTLR.

And ANTLR can generate JS parsers.

Seems like you should be able to parse Python in JS that way.

ANTLR grammars: https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4

ANTLR JavaScript target: https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/javascript-target.md

More info: http://www.antlr.org/

ANTLR is a LL(*) parser generator, the successor to PCCTS. Parsing languages is a complicated subject and actually parsing Python may be an overkill for what you really need but since you ask for a specific solution to your problem then this is something that should get you started.